# Travis-CI resolving non-maven-central JARS

Tags: travis-ci

I have a JAR which isn't in maven central, thus travis ci fails with the below:

> Unresolveable build extension: Plugin
>   org.kie:kie-maven-plugin:6.2.0.Final or one of its dependencies could
>   not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved:
>   org.jbpm:jbpm-bpmn2:jar:6.0.3-redhat-6,
>   org.drools:drools-decisiontables:jar:6.0.3-redhat-6: Could not find
>   artifact org.jbpm:jbpm-bpmn2:jar:6.0.3-redhat-6 in central
>   (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 2]

The jar is located @ 
https://maven.repository.redhat.com/nexus/content/groups/product-techpreview/org/jbpm/jbpm-bpmn2/

How can i tell travis-ci to use this repo?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding missing repos[1]

[1]https://github.com/garethahealy/poms/blob/master/pom.xml#L760